# Why lua table.remove with null index still works

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am seeing the behavior in Lua code that uses `table.remove()` which removes the last element when I am passing `nil` in place of the index . It was counter-intuitive to me.

```lua
> local tbl = {"this","is","a","list"}
  table.remove(tbl,nil)
```

will result in the last element deleted from list

```lua
> for k,v in ipairs(tbl) do 
     print(k,v)
  end
1       this
2       is
3       a
```

is there a specific reason for this behavior ?

Answer (score 4):

> is there a specific reason for this behavior ?

Yes. `table.remove` and `table.insert` are *most often* used as "push" and "pop" equivalents to remove or add elements at the end of a Lua table, treating it as a "stack". Explicitly providing an index is in fact the "rarer" case (and should be, since it has worst-case linear time due to needing to shift items, whereas just pushing/popping at the end is amortized constant time).

Essentially, you can view this as a sanely handled edge case, which turns out to be the common case. Passing `nil` or "none" makes Lua take the "default value" of `#tbl` as index.

`table.remove(tbl)` and `table.remove(tbl, nil)` are not the same; one passes "none" (out of stack bounds) as `index`, the other passes an explicit `nil`. Lua can distinguish these (and some library functions do), but it would be confusing to programmers - who usually expect `nil` and "none" to be treated the same - if it did.

If you're not comfortable with using the statement `table.remove(tbl)` to remove the last element, you might as well set it to `nil`, which is equivalent: `tbl[#tbl] = nil` (except `table.remove` will return the removed element for convenience, but this only matters in expressions).

Similarly, the statement `table.insert(tbl, x)` is equivalent to `tbl[#tbl + 1] = x`. Note in particular that for `x = nil`, `table.insert` is a no-op (this is often considered a footgun).

Comment: Another Exception is that ```table.remove()``` can remove and return an existent Zero ( ```some_table = {[0] = 'some content'} print(table.remove(some_table))``` ) index Key but ```table.insert(some_table, 0, 'some content')``` moans: ```bad argument #1 to 'insert' (position out of bounds)```

Comment: Moreover, an ```table.remove(some_table)``` on empty Table triggers an existing Metamethod ```__newindex``` with Tablename: some_table > Key: 0 => Value: nil

Comment: That seems reasonable - after all `tbl[#tbl] = nil` would trigger `__newindex` with `nil` for an empty table just as well.